# Spectrum of a polynomial operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let us have $A: l^2 \to l^2, A \in B(l^2)$.

$$A(\delta_n)=3 \delta_{n}+i \delta_{n+1}$$

What is the spectrum of $A$?

**My approach:**

We can write down $A$ in a better form:

$$A=3I - iR$$, where $I$ is the identity operator, and $R$ is the operator which moves the components of a vector right by $1$. This is a polynom of $R$: $$p(z)=3-iz$$ is the formula.

We know, that $\sigma(R)=\{ x \in \mathbb{C}, |x| \le 1 \}$

Therefore, $\sigma(A)=p(\sigma(R))$, where $p$ is the polynom we defined earlier.

How can I conclude? :) Any help appreciated.

Comment: You're basically done!  You just need to determine what $p(D)$ is, where $D$ is the closed unit disk.  You don't need anything more than $p$ for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are done. You have shown that
$$
\sigma(A)=\{3-i\lambda:\ |\lambda|\leq1\}.
$$
But multiplying the unit disk by $\pm i$ is still the unit disk, so 
$$
\sigma(A)=\{3+\lambda:\ |\lambda|\leq1\}.
$$
In other words, the spectrum of $A$ is the disk of radius 1 centered at 3.